# Understanding C++ pointers (when they point to a pointer)

Tags: c++, memory, pointers

I think I understand references and pointers pretty well.  Here is what I (think I) know:

```
int i = 5; //i is a primitive type, the value is 5, i do not know the address.
int *ptr;  //a pointer to an int. i have no way if knowing the value yet.
ptr = &i;  //now i have an address for the value of i (called ptr)
*ptr = 10; //Go to the value in ptr, use it to find a location and store 10 there
```

Please feel free to comment or correct these statements.

Now I'm trying to make the jump to arrays of pointers.  Here is what I do not know:

```
char **char_ptrs = new char *[50];
Node **node_ptrs = new Node *[50];
```

My understanding is that I have 2 arrays of pointers, one set of pointers to chars and one to nodes.  So if I wanted to set the values, I would do something like this:

```
char_ptrs[0] = new char[20];
node_ptrs[0] = new Node;
```

Now I have a pointer, in the 0 position of my array, in each respective array.  Again, feel free to comment here if I'm confused.

So, what does the ** operator do?  Likewise, what is putting a single * next to the instantiation doing (*[50])?  (what is that called exactly, instantiation?)

Comment: *ptr = 10 is not "go get the value stored at ptr and change it to 10". It should be "Go to the value in ptr, use it to find out another location, and store 10 there". That's the point of dereferencing the pointer.

Comment: @Uri well met.  edited and updated.

Comment: I should note that this book was outlandishly helpful in learning about pointers in C: Understanding and Using C Pointers by Richard Reese. I would recommend this to any person learning C or C++, as the concepts in it are invaluable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A few comments:

```
*ptr = 10; // Doesn't need to "go get" the value. Just overwrites it.
```

Also:

```
char **char_ptrs = new char *[50];
Node **node_ptrs = new Node *[50];
```

It is easier to think that you have two arrays. However, technically (and as far as the compiler is concerned) what you have is two *pointers*. One is a pointer to a (pointer to a char) and the other is a pointer to a (pointer to a node).

This is easily seen by the declarations of your variables, which, by the way, can be most easily read right-to-left:

```
char **char_ptrs
```

> Reading right to left: `char_ptrs` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`

Putting a * next to a pointer is properly called *dereferencing* that pointer. Since arrays do not technically exist, operator [] on arrays is also a dereferencing operation: `arr[i]` is another way of writing `*(arr + i)`. To properly understand this, you need to be familiar with *[pointer arithmetic](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.vacpp6m.doc/language/ref/clrc03ptarith.htm)*.

More than one consecutive *s: each one dereferences the result of the expression it operates on. So when writing:

```
char c = **char_ptrs;
```

what happens is:

> `char_ptrs` is a pointer to a pointer to a char. Dereferencing it once (for the rightmost *) gets you its value, which is a pointer to a char. Dereferencing that value (for the leftmost *) gives you its own value in turn, which is a char. In the end, `c` contains the value of the char stored in memory at the place where the pointer pointed to by char_ptrs (in other words, the first pointer in your array) points.

Conversely, if you write `**char_ptrs = 'a';` then you are changing the value in that memory location.

Comment: I think Jon earned the accept here.  Kudos to Ignacio as your answer is direct and to the point.

Comment: Thank you. Your question was quite good for educational purposes, so +1 from me as well.

Comment: I think I should also promote the RTL reading trick I mention because of its wide usefulness: what is the difference between a `const char*` and a `char* const`? :-)

Answer (score 6):

`**` is just `*` twice, so a pointer to a pointer.

When put next to a type, `*` binds left, not right. Saying `new char *[50]` is actually `new char* [50]` and instantiates an array of 50 `char*`.

Answer (score 3):

If you find the * notation hard to read use typedef to help make your code easy to read.

```
typedef char*      CharPtr;
typedef CharPtr*   CharPtrPtr;
// Alternative to the line above
// typedef char**     CharPtrPtr;

// When you call new. You get a ptr to the type you are newing.
// new int returns an intPtr. new char returns a charPtr
CharPtrPtr char_ptrs = new CharPtr[50];

// So new CharPtr returns a CharPtrPtr
// In this case we return a pointer to contigious
// chunk of memory large enough to hold 50 CharPtr objects.
```

Comment: No, don't. Hiding the fact that something is a pointer is very poor style, IMHO.

Comment: I agree with Neil in the general case. But Ptr is fine as you are not hiding it (IMHO). But since this is a learning excersise just to get used to using pointers it works. When you get old and lazy like me an Niel the * is just as easy to read and faster to type  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The statements made in your first code chunk are all correct.

```
char **char_ptrs = new char *[50];
```

...means you have an array of 50 `char *`s.

Your assesment of

```
char_ptrs[0] = new char[20];
node_ptrs[0] = new Node;
```

is correct as well.

`**` simply means a 'pointer to a pointer'. It's not an operator.

When you write

```
new char *[50];
```

...you are saying 'allocate storage for 50 `char *`s'.

Comment: Sometimes the syntax is confusing. I prefer: "char** char_ptrs = new char* [50];" To make it explicit, but this also has its downsides.

Answer (score 0):

Clarifying the first section:

```
int i = 5; // i is a primitive type, the value is 5, the address is retrieved via &i.
int *ptr;  // an unassigned pointer to an int
ptr = &i;  // ptr now point to the address of variable i
*ptr = 10; // access (dereference) the value through ptr and change it to 10 (same as i=10)
```

There is no ** operator, just * operator. Like the others have said, ** declares a pointer to a pointer. Because you are declaring arrays of pointers, and pointers are declared with the * operator, you need to declare them as such when allocating memory for them with `new`. Hence, you have:

```
char **char_ptrs = new char *[50]; // allocates memory for 50 contiguous char* (pointers)
Node **node_ptrs = new Node *[50]; // allocates memory for 50 contiguous Node* (pointers)
```

Pointers to pointers do not necessarily have to declare arrays. You can just as well have a regular pointer pointed to by another pointer, as in:

```
char i = 'p';
char *myptr = &i;
char **mysecondptr = &myptr;
```