# Synatx for a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers

Tags: c++

I need to write a function that receives a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to strings.

I still havent mastered the correct syntax for complex pointers.

This is my implementation so far:

```
void func(std::string *(*strPtr)[]);
```

but I'm not sure if this is correct.

Comment: What is the type of argument you want to pass? Please show an example of how should this function be called.

Comment: This might help. [Understanding C++ pointers (when they point to a pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2814512/understanding-c-pointers-when-they-point-to-a-pointer)

Comment: I suspect you probably want a simple `std::string** strPtr`

Comment: `std::string* strPtr[]` is also acceptable

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
void func(std::string** arr) {
    // some code here
}

int main() {
    std::string** arr = new string * [1];
    arr[0] = new string("Hello");
    func(arr);
}
```

`arr` is a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to strings.

`arr[0]` is the first element of an array of pointers to strings.